# exporting table from application UI to word document using apache POI at specified position

Tags: apache-poi

```
1.  Sdfhsh
2.  Dhfsh
   2.1. Sfasd
   2.2. Asdfdfs
   2.3. F
   2.4. Asf
     2.4.1. Acv
      2.4.1.1.  Asc
       2.4.1.1.1.   casc
```

My document consist of above numbering bullets.I want to insert table after 2.1 section.How to search 2.1 section of word using Apache POI?
Numbering items are list items in default style.Which can come under any chapter of reporting document.

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of `Word` document? `HWPF` `*.doc`  or `XWPF` `*.docx`? The numberings are formatted, not typed in? Only searching by numbering independent of text? Numbering items are list items in default style or special styled items? Headings for example? In general it is highly complicated to parse hand made `Word` documents since there are so much different possibilities to make things that look exactly the same but are not the same.

Comment: I am using .docx i.e XWPF. When i am reading document paragraph it only gives text.I want it should read text with numbering also like                                  
2.1 Sfasd
2.2 Asdfdfs 
So,I can find out cursor for 2.1 section.As my input for program for specified position will be 2.1.

Comment: Please update your Question to provide additional informations. Comments are not the right place for this. And please provide all necessary informations. My question "Numbering items are list items in default style or special styled items? Headings for example?" is not answered.

Comment: I answered the question:

How to search paragraph which is numbered with "2.1" in `Word` using `apache poi`?

Please update your question using this title. It will then be better researchable for other users since your question is not mainly about how to insert a table but more how to find a numbering position.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

How to search paragraph which is numbered with "2.1" in `Word` using `apache poi`?

I provide a code which is able reading `Word` and taking into account the numberings which are formatted in paragraphs directly. It will not take into account the numberings which are stored in special styles, which are headings for example.

The code is commented for better understanding.

In general, since `*.docx` files are simply `ZIP` archives containing `XML` files, one can unzip the `*.docx`file and have a look at the `XML`. In context of numbering one will find for example:

```
<w:p>
 <w:pPr>
  <w:numPr>
   <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
   <w:numId w:val="1"/>
  </w:numPr>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:r><w:t>Sfasd</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
```

in `/word/document.xml`. There the `numID` refers to the numbering ID in `/word/numbering.xml` while `ilvl` is the indent level.

In `/word/numbering.xml` one will find:

```
<w:num w:numId="1"><w:abstractNumId w:val="1"/></w:num>
```

which refers to the `abstractNumId` 1, which contains:

```
<w:lvl w:ilvl="1">
 <w:start w:val="1"/>
 <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
 <w:lvlText w:val="%1.%2."/>
 <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
 <w:pPr><w:ind w:left="792" w:hanging="432"/></w:pPr>
</w:lvl>
```

which defines the indent levels format.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordReaderExtended {

 private XWPFDocument document;

 private List<Numberinglevel> numberingLevels = new ArrayList<Numberinglevel>();
 //a List to store the numberings and their known indent levels and counts

 private Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> numIDMaxIlvls = new HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger>();
 //a Map to store the numberings and their actual max indent levels

 public WordReaderExtended(String fileName) {
  try {
   this.document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public String getNumber(BigInteger numID, BigInteger ilvl, String lvlText) {
  //a method to get the numbering number
  String number = lvlText; //"%1.%2.%3.%4..." see listParagraphs
  boolean found = false;

  for (Numberinglevel numberinglevel : numberingLevels) {
   //loop over all actual stored numbering levels
   if (numID.compareTo(numberinglevel.numID) == 0) {
    //this stored numbering is the requested
    if (ilvl.compareTo(numberinglevel.ilvl) == -1) {
     //if the requested indent level is less than a stored one, then the stored one's count must be resetted
     numberinglevel.reset();
    } else if (ilvl.compareTo(numberinglevel.ilvl) == 1) {
     //if the requested indent level is greater than a stored one, then the stored lesser one must be considered
     if (numberinglevel.counter == 0) numberinglevel.countUp(); //if the counter was reset to 0, then count up before using it
     number = number.replace("%"+(numberinglevel.ilvl.intValue()+1), ""+numberinglevel.counter);
    } else if (ilvl.compareTo(numberinglevel.ilvl) == 0) {
     //if the requested indent level is equal a stored one, then the stored one must be counted up and considered
     numberinglevel.countUp();
     number = number.replace("%"+(numberinglevel.ilvl.intValue()+1), ""+numberinglevel.counter);
     found = true; //we have found the requested indent level as actual stored
    }
   }
  }
  if (!found) {
   //if we have not found the requested indent level as actual stored, then it must be created and stored
   //all lesser indent levels which are not actual stored also must be created and stored

   BigInteger maxIlvl = numIDMaxIlvls.get(numID);
   if (maxIlvl == null) maxIlvl = BigInteger.valueOf(-1);
   //maxIlvl is now the biggest stored indent level or -1 if none was stored

   do { //create and store all indent levels between the actual maxIlvl and the requested one
    Numberinglevel numberinglevel = new Numberinglevel(numID, ilvl);
    numberinglevel.countUp();
    number = number.replace("%"+(numberinglevel.ilvl.intValue()+1), ""+numberinglevel.counter);
    numberingLevels.add(numberinglevel);
    ilvl = ilvl.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
   } while (ilvl.compareTo(maxIlvl) == 1);

   numIDMaxIlvls.put(numID, ilvl); //put in new maxIlvl for this numID

  }
  return number;
 }

 public void listParagraphs() {
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : this.document.getParagraphs()) {
   String number = "";

   if (paragraph.getNumID() != null) {
    //if we have a numID, then this paragraph is numbered
    BigInteger numID = paragraph.getNumID();
    String numFmt = paragraph.getNumFmt(); //the numFmt type, "decimal" in this case
    BigInteger ilvl = paragraph.getNumIlvl(); //the indent level of this numbering: 0 = %1., 1 = %1.%2., 2= %1.%2.%3., ...
    String lvlText = paragraph.getNumLevelText(); //the indent level text format: "%1.", "%1.%2.", "%1.%2.%3.", ...
    if ("decimal".equalsIgnoreCase(numFmt)) {
     number = getNumber(numID, ilvl, lvlText);
    }
   }

   System.out.println(number + paragraph.getText());

  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   WordReaderExtended wordReaderExtended = new WordReaderExtended("XWPFwithNumbering.docx");
   wordReaderExtended.listParagraphs();
 }

 private class Numberinglevel {
  //a class to store a numbering level and its counter
  private BigInteger numID; //the numID of the numbering
  private BigInteger ilvl; //the indent level
  private int counter; //the counter

  private Numberinglevel(BigInteger numID, BigInteger ilvl) {
   this.numID = numID;
   this.ilvl = ilvl;
   this.counter = 0;
  }

  private void countUp() {
   this.counter++;
  }
  private void reset() {
   this.counter = 0;
  }
 }
}
```